# Laravel 5 subquery for Eloquent or Query Builder

Tags: laravel-5

Can anyone tell me Laravel 5 equivalent query (eloquent or query builder )  for the following query --

```
select * from questions where id NOT in ( select question_id from answers where student_id=5 ) AND exam_id=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself,

This worked perfectly for me

$questions= DB::select("select * from questions where id NOT in ( select question_id from answers where student_id=5 ) AND exam_id=4");